# Round 37.1-28.75 float calculation correctly to 8.4 instead of 8.3

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding

I have problem with floating point rounding. I want to calculate floating point numbers and round them to (given) N decimals. In this example I want to round to 1 decimal places.

Calculation 37.1-28.75 will result into floating point 8.349998 (instead of 8.35), which will result printf rounding to 8.3 instead of 8.4 for 1 decimal places.

The actual result in math is 37.10-28.75=8.35000000, but due to floating point imprecision it is converted into 8.349998, which is then converted into 8.3 instead of 8.4 when using 1 decimal place rounding.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
float a = 37.10;
float b = 28.75;
//a-b = 8.35 = 8.4
printf("%.1f\n", a - b); //outputs 8.3 instead of 8.4
```

Is it valid to add following to the result:

```
float result = a - b;

if (result > 0.0f)
{
    result += powf(10, -nr_of_decimals - 1) / 2;
}
else
{
    result -= powf(10, -nr_of_decimals - 1) / 2;
}
```

EDIT: corrected that I want 1 decimal place rounded output, not 2 decimal places

EDIT2: negative results are needed as well (28.75-37.1 = -8.4)

Comment: Sounds like you need `roundf`.

Comment: @user3386109 sorry, added example! This actually revealed critical mistake in my question.

Comment: Yup, it makes sense now. That subtraction results in a number (8.35) that's exactly half way between the two possible numbers with one digit after the decimal (8.3 and 8.4). So the slightest error in the calculation will affect how the number is rounded.

Comment: Re “Calculation 37.1-28.75”: No such calculation is possible in a binary-based `float` format, as 37.1 is not representable in the format. **Before** your calculation even begins, `float a = 37.10;` results in `a` being set to 37.09999847412109375, in the format commonly used for `float`. It is **impossible** to represent numbers with two decimal digits in binary floating-point, other than those ending in .00, .25, .50, and .75, and therefore binary-based floating-point is not a correct format to use for such work.

Answer (score 2):

On my system I do actually get `8.35`. It's possible that you have to set the rounding direction to "nearest" first, try this (compile with e.g. `gcc ... -lm`):

```
#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  float a = 37.10;
  float b = 28.75;
  float res = a - b;

  fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);

  printf("%.2f\n", res);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I asked question wrong! I wanted 1 decimal place output, not 2. Thanks for that info anyway.

Comment: @Tmas: Do you actually want to modify the result or just the output of printf?

Comment: Effectively it will be outputted using printf. This is embedded system and I will output result to buffer using snprintf (with rounded to N number of decimals). To my knowledge these printf variations should behave the same in regards to rounding.

Answer (score 2):

Binary floating point is, after all, binary, and if you do care about the correct *decimal* rounding this much, then your choices would be:

- decimal floating point, or
- fixed point.

I'd say the solution is to use *fixed point*, especially if you're on embedded, and forget about everything else.

With

```
int32_t a = 3710;
int32_t b = 2875;
```

the result of

```
a - b
```

will exactly be

```
835
```

every time; and then you just need to have a simple fixed point printing routine for the desired precision, and check the following digit after the last digit to see if it needs to be rounded up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to round to 2 decimals, you can add 0.005 to the result and then offset it with `floorf`:

```
float f = 37.10f - 28.75f;
float r = floorf((f + 0.005f) * 100.f) / 100.f;

printf("%f\n", r);
```

The output is 8.350000

Why are you using `float`s  instead of `double`s?

Regarding your question:

*Is it valid to add following to the result:*

```
        float result = a - b;

        if (result > 0.0f)
        {
            result += powf(10, -nr_of_decimals - 1) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            result -= powf(10, -nr_of_decimals - 1) / 2;
        }
```

It doesn't seem so, on my computer I get `8.350498` instead of `8.350000`.

After your edit:

*Calculation 37.1-28.75 will result into floating point 8.349998, which will result printf rounding to 8.3 instead of 8.4.*

Then

```
float r = roundf((f + (f < 0.f ? -0.05f : +0.05f)) * 10.f) / 10.f;
```

is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry I asked question wrong! Now edited. I needed 1 decimal place output, not 2.

Comment: Thank you! It works for positive numbers, but for b-a negative result still gives wrong result.

Comment: That also seems to output 8.3 and -8.3

Comment: @Tmas :)))) ok: `float r = roundf((f + (f < 0.f ? -0.05f : +0.05f)) * 10.f) / 10.f;`

Comment: Thank you, it works now! It seems to be quite close to my initial proposal, with the roundf addition.

Comment: The problem with the latest version is that 37.10 - 28.79 still outputs 8.4, even though the correctly rounded value is 8.3.

Comment: @DavidRanieri actually no, I'm looking for scientific rounding rules, so that >=.5 -> 1
The only problem is the actual .5 not being always .5 in floats which then cascades in rounding the .5 wrong way.

Comment: @user3386109 fo `37.10f - 28.79f` [I get 8.3](https://ideone.com/k8tCF9), are you using `float`?

Comment: @DavidRanieri that is the old code without negatives, https://ideone.com/6q8rMQ gives 8.4

Comment: oooops, I need a break!

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yup, all my variables and constants are floats. 37.10 - 28.79 is 8.31. When the code adds 0.05, it becomes 8.36 which rounds up.

Comment: I guess it should be added with +-0.005 instead? As per my initial example, 10^(-nr_of_decimals-1)/2

Comment: @Tmas I think the best you'll get is `r = roundf(f * 100.f) / 100.f;`

Comment: @user3386109 seems to work. Would it work for N decimal places as well? You can also post answer for accepted tag.